# I'm trying to solve for the other Acronyms

Tags: python

I have the following strings that I need to make acronyms for:

```
Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers
As Soon As Possible
University of California San Diego
Self Contained Underwater Breathing Apparatus
```

This is my code

```
my_string = input()

my_string2 = my_string.upper()

for x in range(0, 1, len(my_string2)):
    print(my_string2[0::15])
```

but it only worked for the first input. There are three more examples that this code doesn't cover. What I need is for this code to be modified in such a way where it will create an Acronym out of any input.The first Acronym is called "Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers" and once it's placed into the input it returns IEEE as the output. Basically all of the first letters that are capitalized are kept and no lower cased words remain.

Comment: What acronym are you talking about? We need a lot more information to understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: As Soon As Possible = ASAP,  Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers = IEEE, University of California San Diego = UCSD and Self Contained Underwater Breathing Apparatus = SCUBA. These are the four acronyms and their outputs that I'm trying to create.

Comment: I know what an acronym is. You need to show us the problem statement, and explain the intended process by which your code creates acronyms. For example, I have no idea how you chose the value `15` in `my_string2[0::15]`.

Comment: The current code that is listed above only works for Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers which gives you and output of IEEE. And now I'm trying to find out in what way that I can modify this code that will give out all of the four of the correct outputs to all of the inputs.

Comment: An acronym is a word formed from the initial letters of words in a set phrase. Write a program whose input is a phrase and whose output is an acronym of the input. If a word begins with a lower case letter, don't include that letter in the acronym. Assume there will be at least one upper case letter in the input.

Ex: If the input is:

Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers
the output is:

IEEE

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: Okay. In your own words, *how* does your code get the correct output for that input?

Comment: the "my_string" that you see above has been assigned "input() " which means you can enter whatever text that you need to enter. The second assignment which is "my_string2 " has been assigned "My_string.upper()" which makes Any letter that is entered into the input for "my_string" a capital letter. The for loop that you see next will use it's given range to make sure that the output is printed once and doesn't become infinite. The Len function inside the for loop will then return the number of characters that you have entered for the string.

Comment: Finally the print statement below prints the output which is my_string2 which is whatever characters that are returned form the Len function. those brackets that you see holding 0::15 hold the full amount of characters but then skips over 15 to the next character starting with the first.

Comment: Okay. First off, the `for` loop serves no purpose here; it will loop exactly once regardless, and you could just do the inner step - there is no reason for it to "become infinite". But more importantly, why do you skip 15 characters, and not some other number of characters? What is your reasoning for this?

Comment: So it Starts With the capital I in Institute, jumps over to capital E in Electrical, jumps over to another capital E in Electronics, and finally jumps over to the final capital E in Engineers. Ignoring all lowercase letters.

Comment: I was playing around with that bracket and when I put 15 in there and ran the program I gave the correct output. The reason as to why I think it works is because it also counted the white spaces that also reside within the string and it happen to have the right amount of characters.

Comment: I don't think that's what actually happens. If you actually count 15 characters, you'll find that you what you get is the second, lowercase e from El**e**ctrical, El**e**ctronics and Engin**e**ers.

Comment: Think about this again. Can you explain to me, in plain English, a rule that tells you whether or not a given character from the input should go into the output?

Comment: What? I have no idea what you're talking about now. Just the `print(my_string2[0::15])` by itself cannot be an infinite loop. I have no idea what you mean by "put the zero by itself".

Comment: According to the instructions, I am supposed to write a program that whose input is a phrase and its output is an acronym of that phrase.It also says that if a word begins with a lower case letter I'm not supposed to include it in the acronym meaning the output should have all capital letters. It wants me to assume that there is at least one uppercase letter in the input. It doesn't specify anything else so I'm left to assume that it wants every capital letter that is inside the phrase.

Comment: That's the print statement. I'm talking about the zero that you see in the for loop next to the 1.  for x in range(0, 1, len(my_string2)):

Comment: " It doesn't specify anything else so I'm left to assume that it wants every capital letter that is inside the phrase" Okay, so now you have a rule that tells you which letters to put: the ones that are capital letters. Can you write Python code that checks each character? Can you write Python code that checks whether a character is a capital letter?

Comment: To be honest, not where I'm at with my current stage in coding. However I was able to find what I was looking for. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to programming so I bet the way I did it is a bit funky, but this worked for me on my zybooks lab:

```
Name = input()
AStart = Name.split()
AFinal = ''

for string in AStart:
    if string[0].isupper():
        AFinal += string[0] + '.'
print(AFinal)
```

Comment: This returned only the first letters of words that were capitalized when inputted and a '.' in between. So, the input 'University of California San Diego' output 'U..C.S.D.'

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex based solution which looks for words that start with a capital letter and extracts their starting letter, then `join`s all them together to make the acronym:

```
import re

strings = [
           'As Soon As Possible',
           'Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers',
           'University of California San Diego',
           'Self Contained Underwater Breathing Apparatus'
           ]

for s in strings:
    acronym = ''.join(re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]', s))
    print(acronym)
```

If you don't want to use regex, you can just split the strings and test the first character of each word to see if it is uppercase:

```
for s in strings:
    acronym = ''.join(w[0] for w in s.split(' ') if w[0].isupper())
    print(acronym)
```

In either case the output is:

```
ASAP
IEEE
UCSD
SCUBA
```

To run from input, use this code:

```
import re
s = input()
acronym = ''.join(re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]', s))
print(acronym)
```

Or:

```
s = input()
acronym = ''.join(w[0] for w in s.split(' ') if w[0].isupper())
print(acronym)
```

[Demo on ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Y5T5oG)

Comment: It works, but it outputs all four of them at once. The program that I am looking for is one that will output the right acronym of the phrase when it's typed into the input individually.

Comment: I placed your code into the compiler only this time I replaced the all phrases in strings with the input() function. It gave me the same output but it's format is incorrect. The acronym output was vertical with massive spaces between each letter. So all that is needed is some code to modify it so that the output is both horizontal and the capital letters are next to each other with no spaces in between. Just like the output that was given in your original code.

Comment: @NajahJohnson as long as you put all the input it should work fine. See the updated answer and demo

Comment: Got it, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
full_string = input("Enter Text: ")

string_list = full_string.split()

acronym = ""
for string in string_list:
    acronym += f"{string[0].upper()}"

print(acronym)
```

output:

```
Enter Text: This is a long string please be kind
TIALSPBK
```

Comment: It's close, but not exactly what I was looking for. Sorry that I wasn't more specific as to what I was searching for. The comment has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is what I used.

phrase = str(input()).rstrip() #gets the phrase and makes string sanitized
for char in phrase:            #goes through every char
    x = char                   #Did this to make it easier to keep track
    if x.isupper() == True:    #The char loop check if the value is true or not
        print(x, end='')       #print the true uppercase, end print on 1 line.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).